# How to spy a callback argument

Tags: javascript, sinon

I have a function like this:

```
var updateSomething = function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
  ...
  db.update(arg, function(err, res) {
    callback(err, res);
  });
};
```

I'm testing an API doing some requests that internally call to this function and I'm interested in known the callback value when it's called, How can I spy with Sinon the value of **res** and **err** in my unit test?

Comment: That's where dependency injection comes in handy. There's actually a nice getting started video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0X1Ns2NRfks&list=LL0OkHqip6ufJ94z9og1nIHw&index=4

Comment: Good information, thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your API takes `callback` argument from outside:

```
var callbackSpy = sinon.spy();

yourAPI.fetchSomething(arg1, arg2, callbackSpy);

console.log(callbackSpy.args[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'm not taking callback from outside in that case would be much easier I wouldn't need an Spy to get values

Comment: Oh, right... Well, I guess I'm retarded then :D Jokes aside, what you're asking is impossible if `updateSomething` is defined as a private variable

Comment: I'm starting to think that it's impossible to check, as you guessed updateSomething is a private function :)